# Linked SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: remote-desktop, sql, oracle9i

Getting this error when executing SQL Server query only when connected via remote Desktop.

When running the query from desktop, no problem.  Is this a tsnNames issue?

Linked server to Oracle 9i

Server: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
OLE DB provider 'MSDAORA' reported an error.
[OLE/DB provider returned message: Unspecified error]
[OLE/DB provider returned message: ORA-01041: internal error. hostdef extension doesn't exist
]
OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'MSDAORA' ICommandText::Execute returned 0x80004005:   ].

---

Here's the information for one of my connections:

```
Product name: Oracle
Data source: xxxx.world
Provider string: MSDAORA
```

I used the Oracle 9i driver for the DSN

Here's the tnsnames entry:

```
xxx.world =
      (DESCRIPTION= 
        (ADDRESS_LIST= 
          (ADDRESS=
         (COMMUNITY=tcp.world)
         (PROTOCOL=tcp)
         (HOST=gvx0aidwh01p.xxxx.com)
         (PORT= 1521)
          )
         ) 
        (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SID=idwp5)
          )
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not think this to be a `TNSNAMES` issue if it works from your desktop.  Linked server connections are all made relative to the SQL Server instance.  That is, the TNSNAMES file is set up on the machine hosting SQL Server so that the linked server can find the appropriate entry.  If it's working one place, it should be working everywhere.

I have set up quite a few linked servers to Oracle, but I'm not an Oracle expert.  I dug around a little and did find this found this on an Oracle error code reference:

> ORA-01041: internal error. hostdef
>   extension doesn't exist
>       Cause: Pointer to hstdef extension in hstdef is null.
>       Action: Report as a bug

It might be something you need to call Oracle support on.

If you could also give us some information on your linked server configuration we might be able to spot something else.

Comment: I updated my question with the server config info

Comment: @Jerid I don't see anything wrong in the tnsnames excerpt you posted.  Are you connecting via remote desktop as the same user you log in as on the PC where it's working?

Comment: I will double check with him, but I belive so.  I'm being told that others can connect via RD and are not having any problems.

Comment: Yes, developer is using domain login for both.

Comment: Someone suggested recreating his profile on the box, we are going to start there.

Thanks for your help